# JavaScript OM to Approve Designer Workflow Task

Tags: 2010, javascript, client-object-model, designer-workflow, approval-process

I have a SharePoint Designer 2010 approval workflow and I am attempting to approve the tasks via JavaScript Client Object Model. I am able to change all of the fields to "Completed"/"Approved" but the WF never seems to notice the change.

Has anyone ever successfully completed an approval task for the built in approval WF customized with SP Designer? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the following fields (Internal Names) to the values given:

```
approvalValues["WorkflowOutcome"] = "Approved";
approvalValues["FormData"] = "Completed";
approvalValues["Status"] = "Approved";
approvalValues["PercentComplete"] = 1;
approvalValues["Completed"] = true;
```

The key here was `Status`, `FormData`, and `Completed`. It was no way obvious to me that those would be required to be set to the values given. "Approved" is not even listed as a possible value for `Status`.