# Approve Task from Javascript

Tags: workflow, javascript, integrate-remedy-sp2013

I have the **List1** which creates a **Task** when an item is inserted. 
I have to approve this task via Javascript. I found some examples, one of these:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("MySiteUrl");
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('MyTasks');

var oListItem = oList.getItemById(1);
oListItem.set_item('WorkflowOutcome', 'Approved');
oListItem.set_item('FormData', 'Approved');
oListItem.set_item('Status', 'Genehmigt');
oListItem.set_item('PercentComplete', 1);
oListItem.set_item('Completed', true);
oListItem.update();

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(..);
```

All the fields but `WorkflowOutcome` are update and the workflow does not continue.
What can I do in order to change the state of `WorkflowOutcome` and make the wolkflow continue?

Comment: Some voice in the back of my head says WorkflowOutCome wants a number, not (localized) Strings. And I think Completed is a Formula which uses [% Complete], so setting it to true doesn't do anything

Comment: Well, if i look to the definition of `Completed `, it says `Yes/No`-Field.... And about `WorkflowOutCome `, looking on the examples on the web, all people set a string..

Comment: Those voices in the back of my head.... a good thing I run on Lithium

Comment: And those voices keep talking... you have a German word for Status, does WorkflowOutcome need to be localized??

Comment: My SP is in German and also its values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been stuck on the same problem as Emaborsa. It's not well documented but Status and FormData (and Completed) are important fields. Status field in particular has to be set to "Approved" even though the field's valid choices for my install shows as

```
<Field Type="Choice" ID="{c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76}" Name="Status" DisplayName="Status" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Status" ColName="nvarchar4" Indexed="TRUE" Version="1" RowOrdinal="0"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Not Started</CHOICE><CHOICE>In Progress</CHOICE><CHOICE>Completed</CHOICE><CHOICE>Deferred</CHOICE><CHOICE>Waiting on someone else</CHOICE></CHOICES><MAPPINGS><MAPPING Value="1">Not Started</MAPPING><MAPPING Value="2">In Progress</MAPPING><MAPPING Value="3">Completed</MAPPING><MAPPING Value="4">Deferred</MAPPING><MAPPING Value="5">Waiting on someone else</MAPPING></MAPPINGS><Default>Not Started</Default></Field>
```

this can been seen via rest api. /_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('tasks')/Fields

A really old post mentions similar problem in 2010. [JavaScript OM to Approve Designer Workflow Task](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79745/javascript-om-to-approve-designer-workflow-task)

You might want to try setting Status to "Approved" instead of 'Genehmigt' even though you are using German. Also, You should try approving a simple approval workflow that is close to out-of-the-box.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that `WorkflowOutcome` has to be in english, `Status` can also be in another language.

Answer (score 0):

This code works in updating task correctly.

```
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Workflow Tasks");
    var item = list.getItemById(2);
    item.set_item('Completed',true);
    item.set_item('PercentComplete',1);
    item.set_item('FormData','Completed');
    item.set_item('Status','Approved');
    item.set_item('WorkflowOutcome','Approved');
    item.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
         alert('Updated successfully');
      },
      function(sender,args){
         alert('Error occured '+ args.get_message());
      }
    );
```

Comment: Doesn't work, i mean...all fields but `WorkflowOutcome` are set and the workflow does not continue.

Comment: indeed strange..I have used this code and it worked..you need to check what is causing the issue.there could be definitely something else going on.

Comment: No sorry, acctually alle the fields get updated, there must have been something wrong. However, the workflow does not continue.

Comment: 'Completed' is a Boolean (fieldtype 17) with Formula ``=[% Complete]=1`` in my default Office365 TaskList; it is a Microsoft special, because it displays the checkbox in a View.

Comment: OK.... might you also be able to solve my problem?

Comment: Not with this.. just mentioning that ``item.set_item('Completed',true);`` doesn't do anything

Comment: Ok. I tried to execute the code without this line, but it still does not work.